# Calculate sum over power of a range of values in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have Several Numbers in A1 through A100. I have also a number stored in another cell, D1. 
Now I want to calculate

```
=sum(power(a1,d1), power(a2, d1), ....... power(a100,d1) ).
```

How can I do that in short form of excel function? I have come across sumsq function that can evaluate sum of square values in a range. 
But I want to generalize for power n, not just 2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the **Array formula**:

```
=SUM((A1:A100)^$D$1)
```

or

```
=SUM(POWER((A1:A100),$D$1))
```

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

[image]

Comment: @run_time_error Thanks for the feedback................ I do not like array formulas.........let's hope someone else can find a non-array solution.............

Comment: no helper columns?  The quick and dirty array formula?  Who are you and what have you done with Gary's Student?

Comment: @ScottCraner  Gary's Student is being help hostage in a Chinese Fortune Cookie Factory.............The helper column solution was embedded in a cookie...........I ate the cookie, discarded the helper column solution, and posted the common sense solution instead...........